# Continuous error 21: "library routine called out of sequence"

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am writing a simple wrapper class around the Sqlite C functions. The environment is Ubuntu 14_04, the version of gcc 4.8.4 and I installed libsqlite-dev via apt-get and I believe that is the version 3.8.2.

The issue is this: If I call multiple functions (the `c'tor` and `exec`) then the test fails. If I place the sqlite functions that my code wraps (`_open` and `_exec`) functions in a single function (I tried in the constructor) then it passes.  The failure is

> err: 21 msg: library routine called out of sequence

And the unit test that fails is this:

```
TEST_FIXTURE(DatabaseFixture, TryToCreateATable)
{
    database db(test);
    REQUIRE CHECK(db);
    CHECK(db.exec("CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT)"));
    std::cout << db.error() << std::endl;
}
```

The wrapper class is the following.

```
database(const std::string& filename)
    : connected_(false), database_(nullptr)
{
    if (sqlite3_open(filename.c_str(), &database_) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const std::runtime_error ex(error());
        sqlite3_close(database_);
        throw ex;
    }
    connected_ = true;
}

bool exec(const std::string& query)
{
    assert(connected_ != false && "The connected is false");
    assert(database_ != nullptr && "The db_ is null");
    assert(!query.empty() && "The string is empty");
    sql_statement call;
    assert(call.statement == nullptr && "The call is not null");
    int result = sqlite3_exec(database_, query.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL);
    // int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database_, query.c_str(), -1, &call.statement, nullptr);
    if (result != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "err: " << result << " msg: " << error() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

`sql_statement` is a small wrapper around `_stmt` which initializes the pointer to null and calls `_finalize` in the destructor. '`error()' returns the string from`_errmsg`.

As you can see I tried to use `_prepare_v2` but that failed with the same error. Would having differing libsqlite versions make a difference - I would expect that it would fail to compile?  How do you check that the libsqlite matches the installed version?  Should it make any difference - I think it should not?

**UPDATE**: I created a new VM and started with a fresh install of Ubuntu 14_04. Got everything needed in the following order via apt-get: Git, CMake, g++, sqlite3, libsqlite3-dev.  Still exhibits the same issue.
**UPDATE2**: I created a fresh VM using 16_04.  Installed everything I did previously except for g++ (already installed) and in the same order.  Still exhibits the same issue. Since the version numbers are different for SQL I think that can be ruled out?

Comment: What do you mean by using the term "multiple functions" in "If I have multiple functions then the test fails."? Multiple TEST_FIXTURE functions?

Comment: By calling the functions separately in the unit test.  So the calls to constructor and exec are distinct steps.  If I put the `sqlite3_exec` call in the constructor and comment out the call to `db.exec()` then the test passes.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Hm, these are the reasons for returning this error: https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=LibraryRoutineCalledOutOfSequence. Does `sqlite3_errmsg` return anything after opening the db?

Comment: I have seen that page.  The error msg in the constructor gives `C'tor: err: 0 msg: not an error`.

Comment: OK, so your connection seems to get closed somewhere between `sqlite3_open` and `sqlite3_exec`. Try using `sqlite3_status`to get more information. https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/db_status.html

Comment: I've updated question due to trying in a fresh VM. I will try your suggestion of trying `_status` and `_db_status`, but the documentation suggests it is more to do with cache hits, reads, etc. rather than the underlying connection.

Comment: Can you create a simple standalone app (in a single source file) that exhibits the behaviour?

Comment: I have just found the issue and posed the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CHECK(db)` macro invocation expands to `UnitTest::Check(db)` - which is declared as:

```
   template< typename Value >
   bool Check(Value const value)
   {
      return !!value; // doing double negative to avoid silly VS warnings
   }
```

This means `db` is copied in order to be passed by value.

If you have a default copy constructor and your destructor closes the database connection using its database pointer, I'm pretty sure this would produce the effect you're seeing.

EDITED TO ADD:  https://github.com/unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp/issues/7

Comment: Thank you! I broke for lunch to find you worked through it!

Answer (score 0):

It appears the issue is related to UnitTest++ and the `CHECK(db)` macro interacting weirdly with the code. Removal of that line allows the unit test to complete and pass. I will investigate further and post an issue to the UnitTest++ project.